# How do you get past the electrified fence in Ravenholm?

Tags: half-life-2

> [image: The fence under consideration.]
>
> Oh my god… *physics!*

It's the third time I play Half Life 2 and for the third time I reach this fence and get stuck. Shame on me!

So, how do you get past it?

Things I've tried:

- destroy the coil on the window opposite side
- destroy the cable
- destroy the coil the other side of the fence

Comment: You mean you never finished Half-Life 2?!?

Comment: @Ivo I mean I looked dumb at that fence for too much time every try until I'd finally "get" it. If that's not a question worth asking, what is? :)

Comment: It's a very good question, I just pity anyone who doesn't finish the game, because it's awesome!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the top of the fence, there's an electrified wire supplying it with electricity.

Follow that to the source, turn it off, and then you can just climb over.

Comment: Oh, right, that becomes apparent once you put off the fire on the previous square.